# LINQ to SQL - Select property differences

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two cases:

**1:** `.....FirstOrDefault().Description`

**2:** `......Select(y => y.Description).FirstOrDefault()`

I suspect that the first case constructs a SQL QUERY that returns all the columns from AAA and the second case constructs : `*SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE*`.

I am right?

What are the other differences between them ? Why use one case over the other?

Comment: This will probably not compile. Did you meant: `(from AAA where c == "XXX" select c.Description).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the post . Now it's clear?

Comment: Once again, you can't do `.FirstOrDefault().Select(z => z.Description)` because `.FirstOrDefault()` only returns one record, so you can't apply a `Select`to it

Comment: I'm sorry again. I'm working multitasking and i didn't see that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your last edit, now it make sense. You are right, `Select(y => y.Description).FirstOrDefault()` would translate to `SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Description]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]`.

The first case depends on the select clause. What you show just tell us that you select the `Description` property of the first record returned. If what you meant was something like `Select(y => y).FirstOrDefault().Description`, yes, it would translate to `SELECT * FROM..` and then you'll get the property from the results.

So,is more efficient to add the field required in the select clause, as in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

you are right!
You want to use a select for making your own models or anonymous object. You would get the least amount of overhead. Hence, why select all the data when you only want to know the description :)